# Actions Class not working properly after ChromeDriver updated to newer version

Tags: selenium, automation, frameworks

I have updated my ChromeDriver to newest version (to 77). and noticed that previously working methods are not working now. Specifically Actions class is not working properly, its not sending data, not hitting enter.

for example this method is not clicking "Ctrl + F". it used to always click before chromedriver update. I am using pageFactory, this method below I am using in my actual scripts and it not sending keys

```
public void PressCtrlF() {
    Actions a = new Actions(ldriver);
    a.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"F")).build().perform();
}
```

it supposed to hit "Ctrl+F" and search box should appear
Anyone know how to resolve Actions class due to ChromeDriver update

Comment: Is your chromedriver in sync with the version of chrome browser under test?

Comment: My browser version is 77 so I downloaded 77 version of Chromedriver as well

Comment: you need to specify the element to have the click work or to release modifier keys...  So something like .sendKeys(element, keys(char sequence)  Sendkeys has an overloaded constructor now:  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.CharSequence...-   Also not real sure if chords work anymore.  If that causes problems add a sequence.

Comment: Also note that the new W3C standard seems to require an element to be an input element or have a "value" attribute:  https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-element-send-keys  Chromedriver is working towards supporting that standard so that could be the issue.